# How to obtain damping ratio from frequency response function (accelerance) in Matlab

Tags: matlab, fft, frequency, frequency-analysis

I want to find the natural frequencies and its damping ratio's of a test sample that is excited by use of an impact hammer and the response is measured by an accelerometer. So far I have got the Frequency Response Function (the Accelerance) by fourier transforming the input and output data. The Accelerance transfer function has a logarithmic scale. Now I got stuck what to do next. How do I obtain the natural frequencies and its damping ratio? The code so far:

```
N =  125000;   %number of datapoints
fs = 12500;   %sampling frequency
ts = 1/fs;


%set the x-axis of graph
x_max = (N-1)*ts;
x_axis = 0:ts:x_max;

%data
Time = data(1,:);
Force = data(2,:);
Acceleration = data(3,:);

Input = abs(fft(Force));    %FFT input force
Output = abs(fft(Acceleration));     %FFT output acceleration

%Accelerance transfer function
Accelerance = Output./Input;

Accelerance_dB = 20*log10(Accelerance);   %Accelerance with logarithmic scale
```

I hope someone can help me!

Comment: Have you considered looking at the step response of the transfer function and determining these from the percentage overshoot and the settling time / rise time?  It's much easier this way.  Also, a link to your data would help.

Comment: you can directly pass your input output functions to the function [`tfestimate`](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/tfestimate.html)